# How to merge / combine multiple PagingData<T> flows?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have two flows in my `ViewModel` which are calling an API for the paging data.

```kotlin
private val pager1 =
    Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 5)) { 
        pagingSourceFactory.create(repository::getLatest)
    }

private val pager2 =
    Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 5)) {
        pagingSourceFactory.create(repository::getSaved)
    }
```

I want a third flow which returns me the combined values of both like below:

```kotlin
val posts: Flow<PagingData<Key>>
    get() =
        merge(
            pager1.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope),
            pager2.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        )
```

This calls the API perfectly (checked in logcat), but the data is only returned for the 2nd flow.

It doesn't return me the data for both the flows. How should I solve this issue?